Get sum of current and previous row data
I am using powergrid table and below is the code to query the database,

    public $symbol;
    public $expiry;
    public $date;
    public $timeFrame;

    public function datasource(): Builder
    {

        $query = LiveFuture::query()
            ->where('date', $this->date)
            ->where('asset_symbol', $this->symbol)
            ->where('expiry', $this->expiry);

        $data = $query->get(); // Retrieve the data

        // Dispatch an event with the data
        $this->dispatch('liveFutureFetched', $data);

        // Return the original Builder instance
        return $query;
    }

Above code will give output of all rows,
Now livefuture contains data with column time where data are imported at 3 min, which means one row with time 10:00, the second row with 10:03, ...10:06,...10:09....and so on.
Now I have a custom filter where I want to fetch data with a defined time frame, say if I select 3 then it will show all rows without any sum of column values, if I select 6 then it needs to do the sum of column values for a row of 10:00 and 10:03 and show output as a combined row in power grid table,
If I select 15, then it should take the sum of 5 rows and show one combined row, I have filter value $timeFrame available to get a filter,
but I am confused about the query, how do I get a sum of column values for defined rows?

Would it be possible for you to edit your question, and add some sample data from your MySQL table, and the expected output with the filters you specified?
